# Why my argument is not defined when I call my function?

Tags: python

I want to find the moving average of one column in my dataframe, I need to define a function with 4 arguments: dataframe, country, column, window to calculate the moving average. Here is my code:

```
def movingaverage (values, country, column, window):
    df = values[values['Countries'] == 'country']
    s = pd.Series(df['column'])
    sma = s.rolling(window).median
    return sma
SMA_5 = movingaverage (values=df, country='Albania', column='data', window=5)
```

But when I call the function, it says: `KeyError: 'column'`
Here is part of my dataframe:

```
Year    ISO_Code    Countries   Economic Freedom Summary Index  Rank    Quartile    Government 
2017                 Albania    ...       ...     ...
2017                 Algeria
...
```

My function must have the 4 arguments. Thank you!

Comment: country = 'Albania' it will be

Comment: It should be a quoted string `country="Albania"`. Without the quotes, python thinks you have a variable named Albania.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but then it says KeyError: 'column', something must be wrong in my function, I think it is this part: s = pd.Series(df['column']), how should I call the column here? Thank you very much!

Comment: You incorrectly use strings in your function `'column'` when you really want to reference the variable `column`. Same goes for how you use `'country'` within the function

Comment: You want to put value of column attribute (not column as string), So if you change your code `s = pd.Series(df[column])` that will work